# Unable to mount volume in docker run command

Tags: docker

## Requesting for help.

## Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY WriteToFile.py . 
CMD ["python", "/myapp/WriteToFile.py"]
```

Docker image:
docker build -t vol:1 -f Dockerfile .

## Running:

```
docker run --rm -v /root/Practice/Temp:/myapp/ vol:1 <br>
```

## Error:

python: can't open file '/myapp/WriteToFile.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

## WriteToFile.py

```
import time
import os

with open("app.log", "w") as file:
    for i in range(1000):
        file.write("Writing to file:{}\n".format(i))
        file.flush()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: try replacing `COPY WriteToFile.py .` with `COPY WriteToFile.py /myapp/`.

Comment: Your `docker run -v` option is overwriting everything in the image's `/myapp` directory with different content from the host.  Overwriting your application code with a volume mount frequently isn't a best practice; does deleting that `-v` option help?

Answer (score 1):

You are already in `myapp`. Update your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY WriteToFile.py .
CMD ["python", "./WriteToFile.py"]
```